# DbContext.SaveChanges Method Throw null reference exception while saving data

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

Am using EF 6.0 for my web application, whenever i tried to save or update data
via EF, it throws a "null reference exception"..
this method is responsible for creating products

```
private Product createProduct()
{
    Product product = new Product();
    product.Name = txtName.Text;
    product.Price = Convert.ToInt32(txtPrice.Text);
    product.ProductTypeId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlType.SelectedValue);
    product.Desciption = txtDesciption.Text;
    product.Image = ddlImage.SelectedValue;
    return product;
}
```

this method is calling "insert product method"

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProductModel model = new ProductModel();
    Product product = createProduct();
    lblStatus.Text = model.InsertProduct(product);
}
```

This method is performing "product insertion function" and it throws exception

```
public string InsertProduct(Product product)
{
    try
    {
        PizzaHuttSliceEntities db = new PizzaHuttSliceEntities();
        db.Products.Add(product);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return product.Name + "was successfully inserted! ";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return "Error: " + e;
    }
}
```

Here is product class

```
public partial class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        this.Carts = new HashSet<Cart>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string Desciption { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
}
```

Here is Trace Info

[image]

Comment: Did you debug to see where your null reference is occurring? Did you google "NullReferenceException" and the common causes of such an error?

Comment: yup,,, i've tried too many times but can't find the source of this exception.. in debugging.... the exception occurs at db.savechanges() in "insertProduct method"

Comment: when i tried at database directly,,, everything works fine but the problem occurs at application... i've checked too many times but can't find null reference

Comment: Is PizzaHuttSliceEntities a dbcontext class? ie Does it extend DbContext

Comment: yup PizzaHuttSliceEntities inherits from DbContext class

Comment: Is this a Web Forms app?

Comment: yup,,,, it is.. the problem is only with insert and update operation, delete operation just works fine ..

Comment: Do you have an .aspx page called Product?

Comment: no.... the page is manageProduct.aspx

Comment: As in, there are no pages called Product.aspx?

Comment: am getting ProductType from database in ddlType and then assigning it to the product as a ProductTypeId

Comment: no... there is no page named "Product.aspx" in whole project

Comment: In my experience, exceptions thrown by the SaveChanges method usually are (or contain) an exception of type `System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException`. That exception type has a property called `EntityValidationErrors` which contains more information about what happened. I'd look at the exception in debugger and see if you can find a `DbEntityValidationException` buried in there.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Actually the problem is with `ddlType DataSource`, i just refresh the schema of `SqlDataSource` for `ddlType` and the problem vanished. Because i did an update to the database and that's why the `ddlType` pointing to such reference which wasn't exist anymore and for this reason `DbContext.SaveChanges` method throwing `null reference exception`
Thanks to all who pay attention to my question